# Creating an alphabet with numbers in 3d using opengl-es

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

How should I create an alphabet with numbers in 3d in opengl-es? I'm trying to create them with the existing primitives, but it's not looking good. Do we have any alternate way to get these things done? If so, please let me know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need them for? Why doesn't a bitmap font work for you? Are you drawing a lot of text? What character set do you need (western, cjk, or some small subset) ?

Answer (score 2):

I understood you are trying to create numbers and alphabets from primitives manually. You can create them in some modeling program (like Blender, which is freeware), it should be easier and you could get good results.